# Cannot find the target folder

Tags: error-message, server

I get an error message when trying to add an asset through a matrix field when I try to save the entry

Internal Server Error
Cannot find the target folder.

I am able to upload images through assets just can't get the entry to save. Any ideas. It was working before without issues?

Thank you for any help
Josh

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the "Restrict uploads to a single folder?" setting in the fields settings isn't enabled. Enabling this, and not providing a valid path will give you that error I think.

Comment: Thanks! I went into the matrix field and it was not checked. But today It seems to be working fine. I was able to add an image and save without an error. Thank you for the reply